# Vanilla JS - Infinite Auto play Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm going to make a responsive slider that automatically plays.The code I had at first is this.
It's working properly.

However, I'm going to separate the code because it doesn't play automatically.
I tried to auto-play the slides through `setInterval(slider,3000)`, but it didn't work properly.

Realizing that it is a problem caused by all the content in the 'function slider', I separated the button from the press to create two functions, but it did not work. I don't know what to do...

```js
function slider() {
        let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
            slider = document.querySelector(".slider"),
            last = slider.lastElementChild,
            first = slider.firstElementChild,
            btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

        slider.insertBefore(last, first);

        btn.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener("click", movement);
        });

        function movement(e) {
            slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
            last = slider.lastElementChild;
            first = slider.firstElementChild;

            const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".active");

            if (e.target.id === "next") {
                slider.insertBefore(first, last.nextSibling);

                activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
                activeSlide.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
            } else {
                slider.insertBefore(last, first);
                activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
                activeSlide.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
            }
        }
    }

    slider();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
          transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.slide.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.slide.active ~ .slide {
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
          transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.slide {
  background:#222;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: aliceblue;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide active">
                <h3>Slide One</h3>
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h3>Slide Two</h3>
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h3>Slide Three</h3>
                <p>1234</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button id="prev" class="btn">Prev</button>
        <button id="next" class="btn">Next</button>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `event` inside `movement()` function to see which button was pressed, you can supply a "dummy" object with the direction instead:

```js
function slider() {
  let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    slider = document.querySelector(".slider"),
    last = slider.lastElementChild,
    first = slider.firstElementChild,
    btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

  slider.insertBefore(last, first);

  btn.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", movement);
  });
  setInterval(function()
  {
      movement({target:{id:"next"}});
  }, 3000);
  function movement(e) {
    slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
    last = slider.lastElementChild;
    first = slider.firstElementChild;

    const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".active");

    if (e.target.id === "next") {
      slider.insertBefore(first, last.nextSibling);

      activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
      activeSlide.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      slider.insertBefore(last, first);
      activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
      activeSlide.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}
slider();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.slide.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.slide.active~.slide {
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.slide {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: aliceblue;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide active">
      <h3>Slide One</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide Two</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide Three</h3>
      <p>1234</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="prev" class="btn">Prev</button>
  <button id="next" class="btn">Next</button>

</div>
```